# does frappe.db.commit() not work in server script in Frappe Cloud?

Tags: python, erpnext, server-side-scripting, frappe

HI I am writing a server script in Frappe Cloud  where I am trying to update a particular doctype(which is NOT THE DOCTYPE I HAVE CHOSEN IN DOCTYPE EVENT) using frappe.db.set_value(), then in order to save it i use frappe.db.commit().
But when the script tries to run I get the following error

AttributeError: module has no attribute 'commit'

Any ideas to whats wrong

change in the saved document data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use of `frappe.db.commit` mid transaction can lead to unintended side effects like partial updates.

You don't need to explicitly commit in your Server Script, Frappe handles those bits for you.